# I changed the password for the database user of my website, updated wp-config.php and wordpress asks to be reinstalled

Tags: php, database, wp-admin, wp-config

I have lost my `wp-config.php` and could not retrive the information that was there. So, I took a `wp-config-sample.php` and put again all the informations, including a new passwaord for the database user. Now when I go the website I'm redirect to `http://website/wp-admin/install.php`.

The database is there, all the Wordpress files and others are there. How can I get my site online again?

Comment: Are you sure that the database username and password you entered is correct? Ideally it should work.

Comment: Yes,I have checked it many times. And I don't receive the "Error establishing a database connection" that usually occurs when there is something wrong with the connection between user and database, what I receive is Wordpress asking to be reinstalled. It feels like WP can't see its already installed.

Comment: Please check $table_prefix value in your new config file and also check in PHP My Admin, whether they are correct.

Comment: @RaviShinde Thank you VERY MUCH! That was the problem! You put my website back!

Comment: Glad it helped.